# Creating JAR Files with Maven: How to change the target directory for class files?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar, maven-jar-plugin

When creating a JAR file using Maven, the class files (or rather the package structure) are placed directly in the root of the JAR file. How can I configure Maven (or the maven-jar-plugin) to copy the classes to a "classes" directory instead? For example, the jar file should have the following structure:

```
- classes
  - com
    - mycompany
      - myapp
        - HelloWorld.class
- META-INF
  - MANIFEST.MF
```

The structure of the sources should not be changed (it's the Maven default structure).

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: **Why** would you want to do that? Keep in mind that Java needs the structure to find the classes.

Comment: It's for my own component server.

Comment: You didn't answered the question? Why would you like to do that? What kind of problem are you trying to solve?